# Getting the list of packages manually installed by aptitude

Tags: linux, debian, package-management, aptitude

There are 3-4 main things that aptitude does and is good at -

a. Upgrading packages - `$ sudo aptitude safe-upgrade -y`

b. Installing packages - `$ sudo aptitude install $PACKAGENAME`

c. purging (removing package + configuration files - `$ sudo aptitude purge $PACKAGENAME`

Now all of aptitude exploits are written in /var/log/aptitude and its revolving gunzipped archives

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [/var/log] - [10030]
└─[$] cat apt                                                                                                                         
apache2/       apt/           aptitude       aptitude.1.gz  aptitude.2.gz  aptitude.3.gz  aptitude.4.gz  aptitude.5.gz  aptitude.6.gz
```

Now I know that the data I'm looking for is probably in those aptitude logs. How do I tell aptitude to only show those packages which I installed anew rather than those installed as part of upgrades, any ideas anybody ?

Comment: What does “installed as part of bicycle” mean?

Comment: @Giles -  oops, gypsies at work, have fixed it now, thank you.

Comment: Gypsies at work?

Comment: As far as i know, apt marks installed packages by user as manual. running `apt list |grep installed |grep manual` (mind not to provide an argument on apt list) should return all installed packages  marked as "manual" and should give a close indication on what are you looking to.

Comment: nope that doesn't work I get 

`[$] apt list | grep installed | grep manual                                                                                        [16:47:22]   

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.   
live-manual-pdf/testing,testing,unstable,unstable,now 2:20151217.1 all [installed]`

Comment: @schaiba - that's a fantasy term being used to describe a mistake happen inadvertently. So instead of saying I did it, I say a gypsy did it, a sort of play on humor.

Comment: Thnaks, wasn't aware of that expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all packages installed through `aptitude` , you should run the following command:

```
cat /var/log/aptitude* | grep INSTALL]
```

**edit**

The follwing command will display the installed package with their dependencies:

```
cat /var/log/aptitude* | grep INSTALL
```

To exclude the `DEPENDENCIES` you can add the `]` or something like:

```
cat /var/log/aptitude* | grep INSTALL | egrep -v DEPENDENCIES
```

There is an example `emacs`:

```
[INSTALL, DEPENDENCIES] emacs24:amd64
[INSTALL, DEPENDENCIES] emacs24-bin-common:amd64
[INSTALL, DEPENDENCIES] emacs24-common:amd64
[INSTALL, DEPENDENCIES] libm17n-0:amd64
[INSTALL, DEPENDENCIES] libotf0:amd64
[INSTALL, DEPENDENCIES] m17n-db:amd64
[INSTALL] emacs:amd64
```

Comment: I did get a few but not sure that's the whole story though because the results are very few. Also I wonder if this is enough `cat /var/log/aptitude* | grep INSTALL` no need for the extra `]` get the same results. For some reason I don't think all the aptitude gunzipped archives are being parsed otherwise would surely have got more results, is there a way to figure out from where the result came, which aptitude* for e.g. ?

Comment: the `cat /var/log/aptitude* | grep INSTALL` will display the installed package with its dependiencies , the ] to excluse the dependencies